# Spider Web Chart with different axis in java , javafx or excel

Tags: java, web, javafx, char, web-crawler

iam searching for a solution to do some "Spider-Web-Chart" with different axies-scalar, for example:

```
1. Axies 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 
2. Axies 0, 100, 200, 300
3. Axies 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000
4. Axies 0, 2, 4, 6, 8,
```

In JAVA oder JAVAFX if there is something available ? 
(iam planing to do that for some excel data, but i found not accurat exel-plugins or charts.)

Best wishes ghali